# How to re-run useQuery and FlatList?

Tags: react-native, hook, flatlist

I use `FlatList` with `useState`.

```
 const [state, setState] = useState(route);

<FlatList
  keyboardDismissMode={true}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={state}
  keyExtractor={(comment) => "" + comment.id}
  renderItem={renderComment}
/>
```

When I change the datㅁ which is contained in state, I want to re-run Flatlist with new data.

So after I mutate my data, I try to rerun `useQuery` first in order to change `state`. I put `refetch` module here.

1)

```
  const { data: updatePhoto, refetch } = useQuery(SEE_PHOTO_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      id: route?.params?.photoId,
    },
  });
```

2. 

If I put button, this `onValid` function will executed.

```
<ConfirmButton onPress={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
```

onValid function changes data and after all finished, as you can see I put `refetch()`.

=> all this process is for that if I add comment and press confirm button, UI (flatlist) should be changed.

```
  const onValid = async ({ comments }) => {
    await createCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        photoId: route?.params?.photoId,
        payload: comments,
      },
    });
    await refetch();
    console.log(updatePhoto);
  };
```

But when I `console.log` data after all, it doesnt' contain added data..
what is the problem here?

If you need more explanation, I can answer in real time.
please help me.

**add full code**

```
export default function Comments({ route }) {
  const { data: userData } = useMe();
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues } = useForm();
  const [state, setState] = useState(route);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(route?.params?.comments);
  }, [state, route]);
  const renderComment = ({ item: comments }) => {
    return <CommentRow comments={comments} photoId={route?.params?.photoId} />;
  };
  const { data: updatePhoto, refetch } = useQuery(SEE_PHOTO_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      id: route?.params?.photoId,
    },
  });
  const createCommentUpdate = (cache, result) => {
    const { comments } = getValues();
    const {
      data: {
        createComment: { ok, id, error },
      },
    } = result;
    if (ok) {
      const newComment = {
        __typename: "Comment",
        createdAt: Date.now() + "",
        id,
        isMine: true,
        payload: comments,
        user: {
          __typename: "User",
          avatar: userData?.me?.avatar,
          username: userData?.me?.username,
        },
      };
      const newCacheComment = cache.writeFragment({
        data: newComment,
        fragment: gql`
          fragment BSName on Comment {
            id
            createdAt
            isMine
            payload
            user {
              username
              avatar
            }
          }
        `,
      });
      cache.modify({
        id: `Photo:${route?.params?.photoId}`,
        fields: {
          comments(prev) {
            return [...prev, newCacheComment];
          },
          commentNumber(prev) {
            return prev + 1;
          },
        },
      });
    }
  };
  const [createCommentMutation] = useMutation(CREATE_COMMENT_MUTATION, {
    update: createCommentUpdate,
  });
  const onValid = async ({ comments }) => {
    await createCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        photoId: route?.params?.photoId,
        payload: comments,
      },
    });
    await refetch();
    console.log(updatePhoto);
  };
```

Comment: can u add your code without this modifications cuz it does not make sense also "useQuery" is not official hook so provide more info about it

Comment: @Engazan I add my full code

Comment: issue here is your custom hooks "useMe" or "useQuery" , cuz they doesnt exist in React, so first of all What makes your component rerender ? when props passed to component changes OR when STATE inside component changes, i donst see anything here just CUSTOM HOOKS, so add "useState" to your "data, also your full code doesnt contains flatlist so this is not full code, so post full code or just parts that make sense